# Watching a directory and redirecting to PHP

Tags: php, file, stdin, pipe, watch

Greetings,

I'm watching a postfix directory using iwatch.

`iwatch /home/vmail/eamorr/photos/new/`

When a new email is sent, iwatch outputs a line such as:

```
[11/Feb/2011 12:23:43] IN_CREATE /home/vmail/eamorr/photos/new//1297427022.Vca01I1e396M000383.eamorr
```

How do I redirect this to a PHP program for processing?

Here's what I've tried:

`iwatch /home/vmail/eamorr/photos/new/ | php /home/hynese/sites/eamorr/emailPhotoHandler/handlePhotos.php`

And here's the handlePhotos.php file:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://stdin");

$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $data;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

It should create a file "testFile.txt" and put "[11/Feb/2011 12:23:43] IN_CREATE /home/vmail/eamorr/photos/new//1297427022.Vca01I1e396M000383.eamorr" into it... But all I'm getting is nothing - the file isn't even created...

I think it's something to do with the piping and stdin in PHP.

Anyone got any ideas?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: `iwatch` output is not streamed to the pipe.

Comment: iWatch accepts the `-c` switch to execute a command on an event. Tried that?

Comment: Ok, I can execute the command, but how do I get the name of the file that was modified?

Comment: print_r($_SESSION) and one of the variables will have what you're looking for.

Comment: I've tried the following command: `iwatch -v /home/vmail/eamorr/photos/new/ -c "echo '%f' > hi.txt "`, but hi.txt is never created!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_get_contents() does not return until the entire file/stream has been read. In this case, that's never. Assuming that iwatch keeps running, iwatch will keep PHP's STDIN open so file_get_contents() never gets to the end.

Try [stream_get_line()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php) or [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) instead. That will give you the iwatch output line-by-line.

*Edit*: also, the command should be `php -f <script>`, not `php <script>`.